# Navigating to the definitions of `defun` and `defmacro` with slime/swank

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime, swank

Emacs version: **26.3**

Slime version: **2.26.1**

---

I start up Emacs.

I open up a simple `.lisp` file.

```lisp
(defun testfn (x y)
  (+ x y))

(defmacro testmc (form)
  form
  `(list 1 2 3))
```

I place my cursor over the symbol `defun` and issue the keyboard-command <kbd>M-.</kbd> (`slime-edit-definition`).

This should bring me to the definition of `defun`.

But it doesn't.

It brings me here:

[image]

I place my cursor over the symbol `defmacro` and issue the keyboard-command <kbd>M-.</kbd> (`slime-edit-definition`).

This should bring me to the definition of `defmacro`.

But it doesn't.

It brings me here:

[image]

Why does it do this & how do I fix this

Comment: Working perfectly for me, SBCL 1.4 and Slime, it brings me exactly to the definition of defun: `(sb!xc:defmacro defun (&environment env name lambda-list &body body)`, `defboot.lisp` line 192.

Comment: @Ehvince does it bring you to the exact definition of `defmacro` & `lambda`?

Comment: I think it should be a little unsurprising that the definitions of foundational CL macros are odd, and that searching for them often results in something a bit surprising.   I would be a bit surprised if that wasn't true in fact.

Comment: @ignisvolens If they're foundational definitions, then knowing where/how they're defined is fundamental

Comment: @JohnDeBord -- "_knowing where/how they're defined is fundamental_": no, those definitions are implementation details. Knowing what the spec says is fundamental. It is neat to be able to look up primitive definitions directly, but not always easy, and not always possible without going through, e.g., C source code.

Comment: @adabsurdum you're right. I never thought of it that way before. Although, it would still be nice to know why this is happening for future documentation

Comment: @JohnDeBord yes absolutely, for `defmacro` too (`(defmacro sb!xc:defmacro` nearly like you, note `sb!xc`), for `lambda`: `(sb!xc:defmacro lambda`.

Comment: @JohnDeBord: Foundational definitions are always weird.  `(defmacro defmacro ...)`, could only define `defmacro` in a Lisp where `defmacro` *was already defined* which is unuseful.  So there are going to be some hoops to jump through to break that circularity & the definitions will be odd.  It's perhaps worth looking at the bootstrap of Closette which is a small enough system to be easily comprehensible but also has to deal with circularity.  There is a version [here](https://github.com/binghe/closette) at least.  (The definition of `car` in CMUCL also used to be entertaining.)

Answer (score 2):

Notice there is a warning in the REPL when trying to find the source of `DEFUN`:

> WARNING: inconsistent 2 form-number-translations

You can replicate it yourself in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (let ((slynk::*buffer-package* (find-package :cl))
               (slynk::*buffer-readtable* *readtable*))
          (slynk:find-definitions-for-emacs "DEFUN"))
WARNING: inconsistent 2 form-number-translations
(("(DEFMACRO DEFUN)"
  (:LOCATION (:FILE "/home/chris/data/src/sbcl/src/code/macros.lisp")
   (:POSITION 4140)
   (:SNIPPET "(setq doc nil)
    (let* (;; stuff shared between LAMBDA and INLINE-LAMBDA and NAMED-LAMBDA
           (lambda-guts `(,@decls (block ,(fun-name-block-name name) ,@forms)))
           (lambda `(lambda ,lambda-list ,@lambda-guts))
           (named-lambda `("))))
```

To find where the warning comes from, you could do as I did first and do a textual search on the repository, or you could use the following alternate method that works better, namely invoke the debugger on warnings:

```
(handler-bind ((warning (lambda (c) (invoke-debugger c))))
  (let ((slynk::*buffer-package* (find-package :cl))
        (slynk::*buffer-readtable* *readtable*))
    (slynk:find-definitions-for-emacs "DEFUN")))
```

This comes from `SLYNK-SBCL::FORM-NUMBER-POSITION`, and the interesting value in the debugger is the source location obtained from SBCL:

```
#<SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE {10369C50F3}>
--------------------
The object is a STRUCTURE-OBJECT of type SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE.
PATHNAME: #P"SYS:SRC;CODE;MACROS.LISP"
FORM-PATH: (5)
FORM-NUMBER: 89
CHARACTER-OFFSET: 3917
FILE-WRITE-DATE: 3825178034
PLIST: NIL
DESCRIPTION: NIL
```

It says the source is the fifth toplevel form in the file (which corresponds to the character offset), and from here, the `FORM-NUMBER` is the 89th form in a depth-first search walk of the form (this comes from the structure's docstring).

But, if I recompile the function `FORM-NUMBER-POSITION` with DEBUG set to 3, the toplevel form read at this position,  `TLF` is NIL:

```
 1: (SLYNK-SBCL::FORM-NUMBER-POSITION #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE :PATHNAME #P"SYS:SRC;CODE;MACROS.LISP" :FORM-PATH (5) :FORM-NUMBER 89 :CHARACTER-OFFSET 3917 :FILE-WRITE-DATE 3825178034 :PLIST NIL..
      Locals:
        DEFINITION-SOURCE = #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE :PATHNAME #P"SYS:SRC;CODE;MACROS.LISP" :FORM-PATH (5) :FORM-NUMBER 89 :CHARACTER-OFFSET 3917 :FILE-WRITE-DATE 3825178034 :PLIST NIL :DESCRIPTION NIL)
        FORM-NUMBER = 89
        PATH-TABLE = #((0 0))
        POS-MAP = #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQ :COUNT 126 {103B227EA3}>
        POS-MAP#1 = #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQ :COUNT 126 {103B227EA3}>
        STREAM = #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {7F3E0350D953}>
        TLF = NIL
        TLF#1 = NIL
        TLF-NUMBER = 5
```

In `read-source-form`, you can see that the form is being read inside a `(ignore-errors (read ...))` form, which returns NIL in case of error. I tried calling `(read ...)` only but this somehow did not invoke the debugger, so I did the same thing as above and explicitly invoked it on any condition.

There is an error, namely that the package "SB-XC" does not exist, which is expected since, if I am not mistaken, this is a package that only exists during the compilation of SBCL itself.

I think you should contact the <del>SBCL</del> SLY developers and file a bug for this directly, they would certainly have a better idea of how to fix the behaviour (feel free to link to your question in addition to giving the usual details of the bug report).

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing pretty much what you're seeing.

Defun (line 280 of defboot.lisp) is a macro, which is defined in terms of defun-expander (line 230 of defboot.lisp) which is what you're seeing.

Whereas, defmacro takes you directly to its definition (line 15 of defmacro.lisp) which is what you're seeing.

It seems to be doing useful things.

I defined a new function 'addmore'

```
(defun addmore (x y z)
  (testfn x (testfn y z)))
```

I compiled it all, and M-. on 'addmore' takes me to the definition of testfn.

So I think it's all working.